# Is it possible to animate UILabel's textcolor change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
 UIView.animateWithDuration(5, animations: {
        myLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    })
```

Label textcolor just changes instantly

Comment: Oh I'm so blind. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
[UIView transitionWithView:myLabel duration:0.25 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

Comment: Great :) Can you please accept this answer by clicking the green tick :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me for some reason.  It is suddenly making the change instead of gradual during the animation. :(

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. The first animation changes too quickly and does not respect the interval.

Answer (score 6):

I write down the code for `Objective-C` and `Swift`

**animation types**

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIViewAnimationOptions) {
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut            = 0 << 16, // default
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn               = 1 << 16,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut              = 2 << 16,
UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear               = 3 << 16,

UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone            = 0 << 20, // default
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft    = 1 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight   = 2 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp          = 3 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown        = 4 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve   = 5 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop     = 6 << 20,
UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom  = 7 << 20,
} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS(4_0);
```

**coding** for `Objective-C`

```
[UIView transitionWithView:myLabel duration:0.20 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

**coding** for `Swift`

```
  UIView.transition(with: myLabel, duration: 0.20, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {() -> Void in
        self.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
    }, completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though you say the accepted answer works, (1) you need to use `TransitionCrossDissolve` instead of `CurveEaseInOut`; (2) while testing, I noticed that in Swift, it seems as if you can't add a subview immediately before animating it. (I think it's a bug.)

Seeing as `myLabel` appears to be local in your example (since global variables would have to be written as `self.myLabel` within the block closure), there's a good chance you've added the `myLabel` subview within the same method as the animation and without a delay.

So if you still run into problems, I recommend (1) making `myLabel` global and (2) adding a delay between adding the subview and performing the animation on that subview, ex:

```
    self.view.addSubview(myLabel)
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "animate", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func animate() {
    UIView.transitionWithView(myLabel, duration: 5.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        self.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Only works for me with NSTimer, thanks !

Comment: The bug mentioned where a subview can’t be animated   immediately after adding it still sadly seems to be present.