# Title label text color will not animate correctly in UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button that will change it's background color to that of the title labels when highlighted, and the title label will change its color to white. My code is like so:

```
import UIKit

class AlertStyleButton: UIButton {

    var buttonColor: UIColor?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        buttonColor = titleColor(for: .normal)
    }

    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            guard let buttonColor = buttonColor else {
                return
            }
            if isHighlighted {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState())
                    self.backgroundColor = buttonColor
                })
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    self.setTitleColor(buttonColor, for: UIControlState())
                    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                })
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The button color seems to animate correctly as the button is pressed and depressed. However the text will not animate to the white color. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Change to self.setTitleColor(buttonColor, for: .normal)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577443/is-it-possible-to-animate-uilabels-textcolor-change

Comment: @karthikeyan doesn't make any difference

Comment: @srinivasn how should I set the title label color in`transitionWithView`? I tried putting `self.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)` in the animation block and the effect is unchanged, still not animating to white.

Comment: UIView.transition(with: someview,
                                    duration:0.6,
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft,
               animations: {
                   // do something
           }, completion:{
               finished in
               // do something
           })

Comment: someview means give the label

Answer (score -1):

To set title color of an `UIButton` you need to explicitly use the `setTitleColor: forState:` method. For example like that:

```
var buttonTextColor: UIColor!
var buttonBgColor: UIColor!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    buttonBgColor = UIColor.white // set whatever color you like
    buttonTextColor = UIColor.black // set whatever color you like
    backgroundColor = buttonBgColor
    setTitleColor(buttonTextColor, for: .normal)
    setTitleColor(buttonBgColor, for: .highlighted)
}

override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isHighlighted {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = self.buttonTextColor
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                self.backgroundColor = self.buttonBgColor
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your code above ^ it shows the black background animation fine but the text will not animate to white.